# Interface Builder 3 cannot locate com.apple.imagekit.ibplugin

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using Interface Builder 3 in Mountain Lion. It works well, but for some reason 2 xib files cannot be loaded. The error message is:

```
Locate the com.apple.imagekit.ibplugin Interface Builder plug-in to continue opening this document. Press "continue" to continue opening without resolving the dependency.
```

I'm not sure what kind of plugin `com.apple.imagekit.ibplugin` is, and where should I get it. I can't find it installed on the system indeed.

Comment: Is't crashing? I did at some point get a message like this and my `XIB` was corrupt.

Comment: @rckoenes This message is on a popup window of interface builder 3, which shows up when I try to open the xib file

Comment: It also appears in Xcode, as compiling error, if this is what you are asking.

Comment: Looks like the xib file maybe corrupt, if you create a new one are you able to open it?

Comment: Not sure, I've found these lines in the xib file: <string>com.apple.imagekit.ibplugin</string> is this plugin only available on OSX Lion and not mountain Lion for example ?

Comment: Not sure, you really should try it out.

Comment: @rckoenes what do you mean? I can open other xib files and also create new ones. It works. The only file that doesn't work is that one.

Comment: What I ment to say is, remove the plugin from the `XIB` and try opening it. I'm not sure wether the `com.apple.imagekit.ibplugin` is Lion only.

Comment: @rckoenes there are actually many occurrences of that line in the xib file. I now get another error when I try to open it... Interface Builder encountered an internal logic error.

Comment: "Interface Builder 3 ..." you mean the version released alongside Xcode 3, the last one to exist separately from XCode, and the last to support custom ibplugins? Does that even _run_ on Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error means that Xcode (or Interface Builder) doesn't know about the com.apple.imagekit.ibplugin (which is strange)

In apple's Xcode release notes, since Xcode 4.1, IBPlugins are no longer supported. Therefore, they do not exist in Lion (I believe.) In order to fix this problem, open Interface Builder preferences, and click plugins. If you see imagekit, thats interesting but you probably don't. This is just to check whether you have the plugin or not.

To fix this, you have to add the imagekit framework back into the project. It should work now. If it doesn't, you have to go to the interface builder plugin prefs and add the plugin located in the imagekit framework (under imagekit.framework/resources).

Sorry if it doesn't work because I have not encountered the problem and I'm also running Xcode 4.

Comment: I see, however imagekit.framework/resources doesn't exist on my mac

Comment: Actually if you are trying to find the plugin, maybe try imagekit.framework/Versions/A/imagekit. Imagekit is also included in the quartz framework so add that. Sorry if I am being confuzing and unclear.

Comment: Hello, I reopen this 1 year old post, because I find myself exactly with the same problem, but with xCode5 on Mavericks. Therefore, this time I can't solve it by changing operating system, I need to make it work in the current environment.

Comment: I tried to load the imagekit file contained in the imagekit.framework as you suggested, but it seems not to be a plugin, it doesn't work. Any idea about it?

Comment: Hmmmm, your computer is cursed XD I would just reinstall Xcode. This is weird that you still are experiencing this problem.

Comment: I'm not on the same iMac. The app is always the same, but I always compiled it on Lion in the past. Now I'm forced to use Mavericks and xCode 5. It seems that the imagekit library is now included into the Quartz library, but I can't find the plugin inside the frameworks.